# Python - loops with reading csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to read `CSV` files and get similar words of first element in a row. If there is any, then compare others elements in this rows.

F.e. test_items.csv:

```
name, value1, value2
ball, 2.5, 2.3
table, 112.5, 3.5
pen, 8.1, 3.5, 4.7
```

pin_items.csv:

```
name, value1, value2
balls, 2.5, 2.3
table1, 112.5, 3.5
pens12, 8.1, 3.5, 4.7
```

code:

```
with open('test_items.csv', 'r') as plik:
    tab = []
    for element in csv.reader(plik):
        tab.append(element)

with open('pin_items.csv', 'r') as plik1:
     tab1=[]
     for element1 in csv.reader(plik1):
         tab1.append(element1)                        

for row in tab:
    for row1 in test:
        z = get_close_matches(row[0], row1[0])
        print z
```

In this case a get outputs of empty "[]"

But when I use this:

```
with open('test_items.csv', 'r') as plik:
    tab = []
    for element in csv.reader(plik):
        tab.append(element)

with open('pin_items.csv', 'r') as plik1:
     tab1=[]
     for element1 in csv.reader(plik1):
         tab1.append(element1)                        

for i in [row[0] for row in tab]:
    z = get_close_matches(i,[row1[0] for row1 in tab1])
    print z
```

then it matchs name's itmes correctly, but I'm not able to compare value of itmes of matched rows.

Any suggestion? I'm using Python 2.7.11, thanks.

Comment: What is your script supposed to do? What output do you expect from the input you have provided? What does `get_close_matches` do?

Comment: what is the logic for get_close_matches? you do realise all you are sending to it is the name field of each file? should it return a boolean which you can then compare the two fields?

Comment: get_close_matches compare each "name" from file test_items with each "name" from file pin_items. If it is matched, then I want to compare the rest items of matched rows - I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I didn't use "[]" for possibilities of get_close_matches.

F.e. :
get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('test_items.csv', 'r') as plik, open('pin_items.csv', 'r') as plik1:
    r1 = csv.DictReader(plik)
    r2 = csv.DictReader(plik1)
    names1 = {}
    names2 = {}
    for line in r1:
        names1[line['name']] = line
    for line in r2:
        if line['name'] in names1.keys():
            l1 = names1['name']
            l2 = line
            # do whatever you want with them here
```

This is assuming that the name field is unique in the csv

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have to use difflib library to match similar items ('name'), so I use get_close_matches. I got error "    l1 = names1['name']
KeyError: 'name' "

Comment: The script: "with open('test_items.csv', 'r') as plik, open('pin_items.csv', 'r') as plik1:
    r1 = csv.DictReader(plik)
    r2 = csv.DictReader(plik1)
    names1 = {}
    names2 = {}
    for line in r1:
        names1[line['name']] = line


    for line in r2:
        if get_close_matches(line['name'], names1.keys()):
            l1 = names1['name']
            l2 = line"

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what your asking for?

```
with open('test_items.csv', 'r') as plik:
    tab = {}
    for line in plik:
        line = line.split(',')
        tab[line[0]] = line[1:]

with open('pin_items.csv', 'r') as plik1:
    for line in plik1:
        line = line.split(',')
        match = str([i for i in tab.keys() if line[0] in i][0])
        if match:
            tab[match] = tab[match].append(line[1:])
```

Comment: You might also want to change `match = str([i for i in tab.keys() if line[0] in i][0])` to `match = [i for i in tab.keys() if line[0] in i]`. In the case that match doesn't find any, this might give an IndexError. You could do the selection after `if match`